# How to call Twig extension filter or function from PHP (controller / service / other twig extension etc )?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have some filters which I am using in twig, e.g. number_format .

Now I want to use this same extension in services, How can I call it ?

Comment: Twig extensions are just services.  Grab it like any other service then call the methods as desired.  I will say this.  You might consider putting something like a "number_format" inside of a data transformer and then injecting it into your custom twig extension.  Then you can access the data transformer without trying yourself to a twig extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create service number_format and then invoke it in twig extenstion.
In this way you can use it in twig and other services :)

Comment: yeah, can we not directly call twig extension filter or function from anywhere outside twig template ?